# how to match correspond value in dict python username password

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, authentication

I have a .txt file with multiple (username, password) pairs like this:

```
jack : ace
```

I wrote a code to let a user input their name and password, and verify these in the database:

```
data={}
with open("user.txt", "r") as f:
for line in f.readlines():
    name,password = line.strip().split(":")
    data[str(name)]=str(password)

counter = 3
while True: 
    print "Log In"
    username = raw_input ("Username : ").lower()
    pword = raw_input ("Password : ").lower()

    for username in data:
        if data[name] == password :
            print "Welcome Misterrr"
            break
        if data[username] != password :
            print "Boo Boo .Suckerr!!"
            counter = counter - 1
    if counter == 0:
        print "Limit try reached already.Bye!"
        break
```

The problem is that after the user input their username and password, the code won't follow the loop, it won't break and it seems that it doesn't really match the user input values to the dictionary values. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 main problems:

- First, you don't really use the values input by the user... : `username` is overwritten when you enter the for loop, and `pword` is never called after creation.
- Second, the `break` you use when the login is successful only breaks out of the for loop, not the while loop.

Fixed logic:

```
counter = 3
done = False

while done is False: 
    print "Log In"
    username = raw_input ("Username : ").lower()
    pword = raw_input ("Password : ").lower()

    # Check if the user exists in the database or not
    if username not in data.keys():
        print "Never seen this name before!..."
        counter = counter - 1
    else:
        # Check if the input password matches the database password
        if data[username] == pword :
            print "Welcome Misterrr"
            done = True
        else:
            print "Boo Boo .Suckerr!!"
            counter = counter - 1
    if counter == 0:
        print "Limit try reached already.Bye!"
        break
```

Comment: helps me a lot.I understand better now.

Comment: Great! You can accept the answer if it solved your problem :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers